laravel is not storing the URL that I make in database
I am trying to save data through my **Laravel **form and Controller the two variables make a URL so when I click so it need to save with the URL that it develop
through that URL parameters and server IP so it need to go to save in database but I try to save it is saving all information just not saving this url  in table
    public function store(Request $request) { // Create a new AvatarLead instance $avatarLead = new AvatarLead;
    $avatarLead->agent_id = $request->agent_id;
    $avatarLead->agent_name = $request->agent_name;
    $avatarLead->lead_id = $request->lead_id;
    $avatarLead->dailer_no = $request->dailer_no;
    $avatarLead->age = $request->AGE;
    $avatarLead->verifier_name = $request->verifier_name;
    $avatarLead->center = $request->center;
    $avatarLead->list_id = $request->list_id;
    $avatarLead->recording_filename = $request->recording_filename;
    $avatarLead->phone_number = $request->phone_number;
    $avatarLead->campaign = $request->campaign;
    $avatarLead->closer = $request->closer;
    $avatarLead->group_a = $request->group_a;
    $avatarLead->server_ip = $request->server_ip;
    $avatarLead->dispo = $request->dispo;
    $avatarLead->recording_id = $request->recording_id;
    $avatarLead->entry_list_id = $request->entry_list_id;
    $avatarLead->user_group = $request->user_group;
    $avatarLead->list_name = $request->list_name;
    $avatarLead->list_description = $request->list_description;
    $avatarLead->entry_date = $request->entry_date;
    $avatarLead->closer_name = $request->closer_name;
    $avatarLead->dialername = $request->dialername;
    $avatarLead->centername = $request->centername;
    $avatarLead->xferSubmission = $request->xferSubmission;

   
    $recordingLink = "http://{$request->server_ip}/RECORDINGS/MP3/{$request->recording_filename}-all.mp3";
    $avatarLead->recording_link = $recordingLink;

    // Save the AvatarLead instance to the database
    $avatarLead->save();

    // Redirect back to the form with a success message
    return redirect()->route('display')->with('success', 'Avatar lead created successfully.');
} `

these are the variables that will make a URL and URL will be stored in database URL recording area when I submit everything is going there except one URL
     $recordingLink = "http://{$request->server_ip}/RECORDINGS/MP3/{$request->recording_filename}-all.mp3";
    $avatarLead->recording_link = $recordingLink;

    // Save the AvatarLead instance to the database
    $avatarLead->save();

    // Redirect back to the form with a success message
    return redirect()->route('display')->with('success', 'Avatar lead created successfully.');  


could you send the whole app code on some gitlab or github ? or at least the "working - non working example" ?

Write AvatarLead code

is that recording_link is added in your AvatarLead model's fillable

the     $recordingLink = "http://{$request->server_ip}/RECORDINGS/MP3/{$request->recording_filename}-all.mp3";
combination of this will save in avatarlead  then recording_link
